# Conditionally include Apache configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In a mulit-domain setup I use a huge .htaccess file with the following conditions to skip a lot of rewrite rules depending on the HTTP_HOST of the requested URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
## skip next 1000 rules, if we`re not on the .com domain.
RewriteRule .? - [S=1000]
RewriteRule ^foo https://www.example.com/bar [R=301,L]
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.uk$
## skip next 500 rules, if we`re not on the .co.uk domain. 
RewriteRule .? - [S=500]
RewriteRule ^foo https://www.example.co.uk/bar [R=301,L]
...
```

As I have several domains with around 4000 rewrite rules in total, I`d rather like to split the configuration up into several files and load those files depending on the current HTTP_HOST.

Is it possible to use the include directive within an expression instead of

```
"RewriteRule .? - [S=500]"
```

?

Something like this maybe:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ ^www\.example\.com$">
    Include conf/com.rewriterules.conf
</If>
```

Or are there even better ways to solve this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in a dynamic configuration file? That will really slow down your server. Instead you should implement such rules in the actual host configuration which is read only once at server startup, not for every single request... In there you define the separate hosts anyway, so it is trivial to use an `include` directive in there to load host specific configuration files.

Comment: you`re absolutely right and I hope this will be possible soon. But at the moment we can`t change the server setup and thus the only way to maintain rewrite rules is htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we can't change the server setup and thus the only way to maintain rewrite rules is htaccess.

You can't do this in `.htaccess` since you can't use the `Include` directive in `.htaccess` files. There is no other method of including a config file. And the only way to include this conditionally is with an `<If>` block.

You could potentially have all the directives inside the `<If>` block, instead of using the `[S=1000]` flag. However, this is not without serious caveats. Whilst the `<If>` expression is processed early, the contents of the `<If>` block are merged *late* ("last") in the request. In fact, it appears to be merged *very late*, after the request has already been mapped to the filesystem. This means that the `RewriteRule` directives match against the resolved filesystem path, not the requested URL-path! So, this would need to be accounted for in any `RewriteRule` directives - or change to using mod_alias `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` for your external redirects, which always act on the requested URL.

You can *potentially* do this in the server config (use an `Include` directive inside an `<If>` block). But the same caveat applies as mentioned above - the `<If>` block is merged *very late*.

Note, however, your syntax is not quite correct. If you wish to match a regex then you are missing slash delimiters around the regex. It should read:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^www\.example\.com$/">
    Include conf/com.rewriterules.conf
</If>
```

Or use a simpler string/equality comparison:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.example.com'">
:
```

However, instead of using an `<If>` block, it would be preferable to have a separate `<VirtualHost>` for each domain and in each vHost you can simply `Include` the necessary file. No caveats.

---

Bit of an aside, but... if all your "rewrite rules" are external redirects (as in your example) for requests that would otherwise result in a 404 (ie. they don't exist) then you shouldn't be doing all these redirects in the Apache config to begin with (`.htaccess` or server config).

They should be in your application logic and only processed "late" when your application has determined it would otherwise result in a 404. This prioritises normal site traffic, instead of prioritising the redirects. With the redirects in the Apache config they are processed on every single request - this is often unnecessary.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^foo https://www.example.com/bar [R=301,L]
> :
> RewriteRule ^foo https://www.example.co.uk/bar [R=301,L]
> ```

Maybe just your exemplified code, but you don't need to specify an absolute URL in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* for external redirects. it could be root-relative: `/bar`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, I`ve learned a lot from it.